# Gulp serve SPrintFImpl(const char *): Assertion `(p[1]) == ('%')' failed error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, spfx

I've been working on an SPFx project on my macbook for a while and its been fine. I have recently got a new macbook and have been trying to get my solution running on my new one. I cloned it from my ADO repository and I have everything installed with the same versions I have on my old macbook

- Node 16.13.2
- Gulp-cli 2.3.0
- Gulp local 4.0.2
- Python 2.7.18
- Python3 3.10.9

I have my node modules install and everything all seems to be fine however, when I run any gulp commands I am getting a weird log in the terminal and I can understand what the issue is. Has anyone had anything like this or know what I can do to resolve this?

```
gulp serve\[48685\]: ../src/debug_utils-inl.h:67:std::string node::SPrintFImpl(const char *): Assertion \`(p\[1\]) == ('%')' failed.
1: 0x1058bbee5 node::Abort() (.cold.1) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
2: 0x104571dc9 node::Abort() \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
3: 0x104571c31 node::Assert(node::AssertionInfo const&) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
4: 0x1044a49a5 node::SPrintFImpl(char const*) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
5: 0x1058b9602 std::\__1::basic_string\<char, std::\__1::char_traits\<char\>, std::\__1::allocator\<char\>\> node::SPrintF\<\>(char const\*) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
6: 0x104547ebd v8::Local\<v8::Value\> node::ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED\<\>(v8::Isolate\*, char const\*) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
7: 0x104547b50 std::\__1::\__function::\__func\<node::binding::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo\<v8::Value\> const&)::$\_0, std::\__1::allocator\<node::binding::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo\<v8::Value\> const&)::$\_0\>, bool (node::binding::DLib\*)\>::operator()(node::binding::DLib\*&&) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
8: 0x104546700 node::Environment::TryLoadAddon(char const\*, int, std::\__1::function\<bool (node::binding::DLib\*)\> const&) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
9: 0x104546503 node::binding::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo\<v8::Value\> const&) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
10: 0x104762ae5 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
11: 0x1047620b8 v8::internal::MaybeHandle\<v8::internal::Object\> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper\<false\>(v8::internal::Isolate\*, v8::internal::Handle\<v8::internal::HeapObject\>, v8::internal::Handle\<v8::internal::HeapObject\>, v8::internal::Handle\<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo\>, v8::internal::Handle\<v8::internal::Object\>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
12: 0x10476167f v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate\*) \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
13: 0x104ff0a19 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
14: 0x104f8b445 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline \[/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node\]
zsh: abort      gulp serve
```